# phpmyadmin changes date when changing any value

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a database with different tables.
Each table has its own columns.
There are tables that have a date field.
On these tables, whenever I try to change any other value, other than date, it also updates the date.

So if I change the name of a user, it changes the name of the user, plus the date is updated as of now, without me trying to change it, it changes by itself.
How can I stop this behavior?

I have tried also with two different phpmyadmin versions.
Also I change them by just double clicking on the column values and making the required changes.

**Update:**
I did in fact update a table value in mysqli and it updated the date also. I will have to check what causes this in the code then update accordingly.

This is how data is defined in the table. (Which is date in English).
[image]

**Update 2:**
Looks like it was attribute on update the real problem. Every date I create had it set by default. So it should be set to blank. The one shown in the picture was it.

Comment: _"Bear in mind that this is just a phpmyadmin behavior, nothing to do with code."_ It probably shouldn't be on SO, then, should it? DBA seems like a better choice. Anyway, there isn't enough info about these mysterious tables for anyone to make any useful comment... but it sounds like there might be triggers on them causing the date to update. I presume your database backend is MySQL? Does the same behaviour occur if you write an `update` query instead of using the PHPMA GUI? There just isn't enough info here.

Comment: I did write an update query and it did in fact change the date. I will check what causes this.

Answer (score 0):

Edit Date Column
on the Drop down menu "Default"
Select
"CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

Comment: I don't think this is relevant. Don't they want to **stop** that being the default value? More to the point, why would the default matter, anyway, if there is a value, which is being `update`d in the OP's case? The default is only used when `insert`ing and not providing a value for that column.

Comment: I don't know why, it works now. I tried with different settings and I do believe it had to do with on update. Though when I revert it back it works without any problem. No idea what changed it.